# Is it possible to work with Maybe more expressively?

Tags: haskell

Happy New Year to everyone!
I would like to write something like this, but I know that find can return Nothing, is there any better way to write than through `Just` and `Nothing`?

```
snd (find (\t -> fst t == 2) [(1, 2), (2, 3)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [**`lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) which will walk over the list, and will return a `Just 3` in this case if it finds the value associated with the given key, or `Nothing` if there is no such value.

So:

```
ghci> lookup 1 [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
Just 2
ghci> lookup 2 [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
Just 3
ghci> lookup 3 [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
Nothing
```

Comment: That's really good, but what if I want to do something like that `y1 = snd (lookup x1 list)` ?

Comment: @student422: you can `fmap snd ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we define `find` as:

```
find _ [] = Nothing
find p (x:xs)
  | p x = Just x
  | otherwise = find p xs
```

Now:

```
find (\(x, _) -> x == 2) [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
-- Just (2,3)
```

If you want to be able to apply a function to the `Maybe` result without having to explicitly match out the value, you may want something like:

```
(>>>) (Just x) f = Just (f x)
(>>>) Nothing _ = Nothing
```

Now:

```
find (\(x, _) -> x == 2) [(1, 2), (2, 3)] >>> snd
-- Just 3
find (\(x, _) -> x == 2) [(1, 2), (3, 3)] >>> snd >>> (* 2)
-- Nothing
```

For a `Just x` result, the function is evaluated with `x` as it's argument. For `Nothing`, `Nothing` is simply propagated along.

Comment: Isn't your `>>>` just a flipped `fmap` / `<$>`? Probably a better idea to teach beginners about `fmap` rather than tell them to define a new function; they'll need to be able to read it, even if they prefer not to use it.

Comment: Especially since `(>>>)` already has a "standard" definition, albeit in the context of arrows.

Comment: `Data.Functor` also provides `<&> = flip fmap`.